# In android What is efficent way for use of Activity

Tags: android, android-activity

**I just want to ask what is efficient way of use activity. Mean use one activity for multiple functionality or use multiple activity for every functionality.**

In  my application working some thing like Category->subcategory->Product listing. In which orientation change design and also need to consume previous functionality state for Back.

Thanks

Comment: No downvote. Please explain your problem properly. I can't understand `In which orientation change design and also need to consume previous functionality state for Back.`

Comment: can you please make question clear ? little bit confusing at last line

Comment: Hi  Mudassir thanks for reply, In my application I use Tab & one of tab I use  Category->subcategory->Product listing functionality.

Comment: I use Tab & one of tab I use  Category->subCat->ProductListing functionality. Also view of all functionality is different for LandScape & Portrait mode. And when I back from any of functionality & go back to previous I resume  last  view status. This is all I handle by using one activity Group & use different activity for category, subcategory & product list. But I face problem to handle orientation & back functionality. Because for this my most of memory is allocated and also processing is increased. For this I just want to ask  if I use one activity for all this , then is it a efficient way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Per the documentation for Activities](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html), *"An activity is a single, focused thing that the user can do".* In other words, each different screen of your application should be an activity.

The only time you should have an Activity represent more than one screen is if it's a recursive action like a file browser; i.e. something that just changes the data that is displayed, but is displayed the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite common to create one Activity for every logical "screen" of your application, but to share the same Activity for multiple "states" (eg. dialog boxes, different modes) of that screen.

The back button will automatically go backwards through Activities (by default) and you can override the back button within an activity to revert to a previous state within the same activity (ie. hiding a panel)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, Activity, in case of Android, is not a synonym for functionality. It is synonym for screen UI. Thus, how you implement your functionality is your choice. You just need to consider the following tips:

1. If you use the same activity for categories and subcategories (using
   List elements), then you need time for deleting items for categories
   (plus, GC also takes time), populating the list with the values for
   subcategories. The weak points here that the user cannot return to
   the previous Activity using back button (this violates the default
   flow for user interactions), the screens are identical for
   categories and subcategories (this can mess the user), it will takes
   a long time for deleting unnecessary elements and populating with
   new elements. Strong point: you will reduce memory consumption for
   your application.
2. The second option is to use different activities. Weak points: it
   also takes time to initialize new activity and to populate the list
   with the values of subcategories, it will take more memory to store
   two activities. Strong point: clear user understanding, more
   responsibility to user's actions (you do not need to run GC to
   delete unnecessary objects).

As for me the second approach is better unless you are not restricted with the memory.

Comment: Thanks Yury for reply, Currently I used second approach that you suggest. But In that when I try to handle orientation of each activity then it need to handle in activity group & due to this I need to public lots of data so that my application can give me Out of memory error. As you suggest in first scenario if I used ViewFlipper & every functionality is add as a child of flipper then I think I can resume previous layout data. But is this correct approach for me. Or any other way that I can manage this thing.

Comment: Maybe for your case it is better to consider Fragments. I just explained for the case of multiple activities.