# Android Use One activity for differnet functionality or use Different activiyt for each

Tags: android, android-activity

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In android What is efficent way for use of Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8709254/in-android-what-is-efficent-way-for-use-of-activity)

I just want to ask what is efficient way of use activity. Mean use one activity for multiple functionality or use multiple activity for every functionality.

In my application working some thing like Category->subcategory->Product listing. So I just want to ask , this is all I handle by using one activity Group & use different activity for category, subcategory & product list (Activity Group because it all in one Tab). OR I use one activity and handle all functionality in it. Which is efficient way. And if possible then any link which can clear this concept more for me.